# Torch-wise masking instead of element-wise

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I would like to create a mask for a tensor based on the existence of another tensor within the first. This is easy to do if I am checking for a scalar, but I could not find a way to do it tensor-wise in the way I need.

What I can do element-wise:

```
x = torch.Tensor([[1,2,3,4],[4,3,2,1]])
mask = ( x == 2 )
```

mask equals `tensor([[False,  True, False, False], [False, False,  True, False]])`.

This is what I would like to do:

```
x = torch.Tensor([[1,2,3,4],[4,3,2,1]])
mask = ( x == torch.Tensor([1,2]) ) #this does not actually work
```

Which would have mask equal `tensor([[True, True,  False,  False], [ False,  False, False, False]])`.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: To be clear, you are talking about searching for essentially a subvector contained within a vectorized slice of a tensor?

Comment: Moreover, is the size of the query vector generally small (length = 2 in this case) or is it going to be arbitrarily large?

Comment: Also, do you want to search only along a single dimension or along every possible "tensor fiber" direction ?

Comment: It is arbitrary length, and it would search over only one dimension so for example
[[1,2,3],
[2,1,2],
[4,6,4]]
it would find all 1,2 across the rows but not the columns